# How to stop action for last three elements of list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, animation

I have some list, and im moving on it by clicks - animating right, left. Also change some class for recognize position and actions. I need to stop animate proces when last three elements of list will be have specify class. So i do this, but it works for only last third back element. Can u help me?

```
if (!js_films_list_top.find('li').eq(-3,-2,-1).hasClass('focus')){
    js_short_movies_list.animate({left: '-=241'}, 300);
}
```

Thx for help.

Comment: [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) has only a single parameter

Comment: `slice(-3)` is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.eq` only takes one argument.  If you want to select multiple at a time, try this:

```
.find('li:eq(-3), li:eq(-2), li:eq(-1)')
```

OR try

```
.find('li').slice(-3)
```

Comment: No need for `, 0` ... ah you got it